# Android Studio If Else Conditions

Tags: if-statement, android-studio

I require some help in forming an if else code to show a message. For example, if it is more than or equal to 50, a message "Green Mark Certified" will be showed in textView box. Below are the codes that I did for a simple calculator. What I need is when int sum>=50 and <75, show "Green Mark Certified" in a textView box. Please kindly show me how to code if I want to achieve it.

```
public void onButtonClick(View V){
    EditText e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    EditText e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    EditText e3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    EditText e4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    EditText e5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);

    TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());
    int num3 = Integer.parseInt(e3.getText().toString());
    int num4 = Integer.parseInt(e4.getText().toString());
    int num5 = Integer.parseInt(e5.getText().toString());
    int sum = num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5 ;
    t1.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 2):

This is how the if statement should look like:

```
if(sum >= 50 && sum < 75) {
    t1.setText("Green Mark Certified");
}
```

The conditions are placed in parentheses after `if`, and the code to be executed is placed in brackets. `&&` means "and", and `||` (which is not used) means "or".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the logical `&&` operator to check both conditions:

```
if (sum >= 50 && sum < 75) {
    t1.setText("Green Mark Certified");
}
```

Comment: I tried putting the codes under but it seems that there were a few errors. Illegal start of type, Illegal start of expression, ")" expected, class interface or enum expected.

Comment: @Kendrick please post the exact code you tried. Looks like you missed a bracket somewhere

Comment: It's fine I managed to rectify the mistake.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys